# What are the pitfalls of using a separate SSIS package for centralized error management?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

We have a few loosely coupled SSIS packages that are in charge of batch integration. When they have an error (validation issue with data, or an actual OnError error) then they all do the same thing, they email a message to a distribution list. The content of the message varies, and sometimes other people need to be cc'd on the message. But it is basically the same process for everything.

I am thinking of creating a single ErrorHandler package that has a few parameters (error message, cc address, subject line etc) and just getting the parent packages to run an Execute Package Step when they need to send an error message.

The way I see it, we then have one single SSIS package that allows us to manage what we do with the incoming errors. If we decide we want to write stuff into a log file, or call a web service, it only has to be changed in the one place.

Limited testing so far looks fine. Am I missing something obvious here? Why doesn't everybody do this? Is there a transactional or cascading issue that could be a problem?

Comment: I don't rely on failure emails generated from SSIS for a few reasons. One, if the package fails validation (table changed, excel workbook was breathed on, etc), that can be treated as a "compilation error" and if you can't compile your code, you certainly can't fire error trapping code. Another reason I don't use email as a notification system is that it doesn't mesh well with our development process. "Oh, I didn't get tasks X,Y,Z done this iteration because of production issues" I'd rather have my error notification process open tickets in our bug tracking software which can also send emails

Comment: If you go the email route, be sure that you are notifying distribution groups and not specific users and either way, ensure that you can change the recipients through some externally configurable mechanism. Nothing worse than having to update N packages just because someone has left an organization, gotten married, etc.

Comment: I don't have an issue in general though with writing task specific packages and referencing them from other packages. I have ftp, sftp specific packages. Since you've tagged this with 2012, I will point out that with the Project Deployment model, logging to SQL Server automatically happens (assuming you're running from the SSISDB). My personal preference, were I in your shoes, would be to have a periodic process that sweeps all my error generators (SQL Agent, SSISDB, app specific logs) and then perform notification tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. The plan is to use a single package which will, for the moment, send an email when it is invoked. So that should take care of the "updating N packages" issue. I'm aware of 2012 logging, and we plan to use that. This is more for routine notifications of data validation failures (fields missing values, or with invalid values for example.)

Comment: We won't be relying on this as the be all and end all, but as an "inside-the-packages" mechanism it doesn't seem like a bad approach, especially as the tendency here is to have lots of small compartmentalized packages anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one pitfall we have encountered now we've started down this road is that you have to keep your SSIS packages in the same project otherwise they can't invoke each other.

This negates some of the good reasons we chose to use this pattern in the first place.

For instance, SSIS Parameters can be defined at the package level or the project level, but not in between, so now we have parameters that need to be shared between three packages, but which are visible to/shared across ALL packages because they must be kept at the project level.

You can't organise SSIS packages within a project by, for instance, grouping them into subfolders. The only way to visually organise them is to introduce some kind of naming schema.

There are ways to overcome this, by invoking packages via stored procs or script steps, but these come with their own shortfalls. (For instance, you can specify the Environment you want to use when invoking a package from a stored proc, but how does the calling package know what Environment it is being run in in order to invoke the child package with the same Environment? By Environment I refer to the logical grouping of parameters into environments such as Test, Staging, Prod that can be performed on the SQL Server.)

Microsoft is aware of this issue, but does not seem to want to do anything about it. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779789/ssis-2012-execute-package-task-external-reference-does-not-work-with-ssisdb